# Парсинг сайта после нажатия кнопки (Python)

Tags: python, парсер

На сайте есть калькулятор, хочу удаленно вносить нужные значения и получать данные из итоговой таблицы. Но при отправке запроса таблица пуста. Я так понимаю в данном случаем надо использовать selenium, но не понимаю как это сделать, чтобы после брать html код страницы.

```
https://dogovor-urist.ru/calculator/peni_po_stavke/#loanAmount=10000&dateStart=01.06.2020&dateFinish=09.06.2020&ratePart=1/360&rateType=3
```

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
count = 10000
start = '01.06.2020'
end = '09.06.2020'
url = f'/#loanAmount={count}&dateStart={start}&dateFinish={end}&ratePart=1/360&rateType=1'
source = 'https://dogovor-urist.ru/calculator/peni_po_stavke'
request = source + url
html = requests.request(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'html.parser')
news = soup.find('div', class_='resultAppearing').find('table', class_='judge-table jt-2')
print(news)
```

Comment: Не проще свой калькулятор сделать?

Comment: Нет, так как ставка динамически меняется

Answer (score 2):

Указанный калькулятор заполняет вывод динамически, при загрузке и выполнении JavaScript. Просто `requests` модулем такое заполнение не достать.

С помощью `selenium` будет выглядеть следующим образом. На выходе будет таблица с заполненными данными.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = 'https://dogovor-urist.ru/calculator/peni_po_stavke'
count = 10000
start = '01.06.2020'
end = '09.06.2020'
url = f'{source}/#loanAmount={count}&dateStart={start}&dateFinish={end}&ratePart=1/360&rateType=1'

browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
browser.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find('div', class_='resultAppearing').find('table', class_='judge-table jt-2'))

browser.quit()
```

Для работы потребуется

```
pip install selenium 
pip install webdriver_manager
pip install bs4
```

Я не знаком с `selenium`. Попытался скрыть окно браузера при работе скрипта. Но в таком случае он просто зависает на строке `browser.get(url)`. Не знаю с чем это связано.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = True
browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
```

Некоторые ответы предлагают спрятать окно за видимой областью или использовать `PhantomJS`

```
browser.set_window_position(-3000, 0)
```