# Python парсинг | Собрать контент, отображаемый после нажатия на кнопку

Tags: python, парсер, requests, bs4

Возможен повтор статьи [Парсинг сайта после нажатия кнопки (Python)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1138625/%d0%9f%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8-python), но конкретного ответа на свой вопрос я не нашёл.

Есть сайт https://medspecial.ru/wiki/categories/.
Вверху страницы есть кнопки выбора темы, и в зависимости от нажатых кнопок, контент под ними будет меняться. Выбрать можно сразу сколько угодно тем. Структура html выглядит так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Href** у всех один и тот-же, зацепиться за них я не могу. Единственное что может хоть как-то может помочь это **data-id** и добавление класса "active" к элементу, после нажатия на кнопку.
Я новичок в этой сфере, пожалуйста не судите строго. Рад любым ответам

Comment: Как вы пробовали решить эту проблему самостоятельно? И без помощи selenium.

Comment: Нашёл запрос, который отправляет сайт при нажатии на кнопку. Увидел что он возвращает тот html, который появляется при выборе темы. Захотел понять как отправить запрос самому. Мало что понял. В заголовках ничего полезного, а в данных формы отправляются: ajax: Y, sect[]:  46, sect[]: 126. Этих sect[]'ов всё больше с каждой зажатой кнопкой. А значения у них, как у data-id в теге <a> в структуре выше.

Comment: Теперь думаю что можно через requests.session() это всё дело сделать. Только вот как запрос отправить нормально, я не знаю. Если есть идеи, хотел бы послушать. Вопросы приветствуются. И сайт, который я спарсить хочу, тоже есть в самом вопросе.

Comment: Вот начало кода. Но он виснет на функции loadThemeHtml. https://pastebin.com/muGuUiH1

Comment: responce = sess.post(SITE_URL, headers=categoryHeaders, data={'ajax': 'Y', 'sect[]': themeId})

Comment: themes = {theme.get('data-id'): theme.text.strip().split('(')[0][:-1] for theme in themeList}